# QGIS: Style polygon outline as a dashed line with an inner gradient

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style, cartography

Is it possible to create a polygon outline as a dashed line with an inner gradient (see image #1)? Currently I have a hack job that sort of works (shapeburst fill with a dashed line above in the background color image #2), but it gets very ugly when there are other features in between the outline and the background fill (see image #3)
[image]
*image #1*

---

[image]

*image #2*

---

[image]

*image #3*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use pure white over your shapefill then you can use "Multiply" to blend the **layers** which makes the white parts transparent. Adjusting widths gets me this:

[image]

Here's the style properties for the two layers - the Simple Fill is just a thick dotted white line, and the shapefill is a gradient infill:

[image]

[image]

Important thing is that "Multiply" at the bottom. In "Normal" mode it looks like this:

[image]

and you can see where the white dotted line cuts out the shapeburst. It goes a bit how-ya-doing at corners in places, but that might be fixable. You could also use a white symbol marker round the perimeter to cut the shapeburst.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. Great trick!

Comment: It goes a bit wacky Picasso when I zoom out, but I think that's to do with the units I've used. Some adjustment needed for map perfection...